Are Nekudos always Me’akev?
If one read a word in Kerias Hatorah with the wrong Nikud, and the way he read it does not mean something else, is he Yotze?

To be clear the question is asking BEDIEVED about someone who accidentally made a mistake. Everyone who gets up to read is OBLIGATED to be careful about every single detail in the text. Even those who rule a given accident is still "yotze" still demand we correct/teach him (politely of course) so he can do it right the next time. The community is trusting you.

In the Mesoras Moshe, he brings down that, for instance, an "es" vs. "eis" (alef-tav, with tzeirei vs. segol) is ultimately a function of the trop. As the meaning is the same, and the wrong trop wouldn't ruin the leining, then trop-based vowelizations also wouldn't. I'd imagine the same would go for placing, or missing, the dot in a word that starts beked-kefet, unless that would somehow change the meaning.

Great question, but the answer is complicated. It really depends on the niqqud. For example, replacing a Shva with a quick, light Patach is completely acceptable, since originally, they were identical. However, replacing a Cholam with a Kamatz would not be acceptable. Ignoring Dagesh Hazzak is a significant mistake that should be corrected, but putting a dagesh Kal on a letter that lacks it is completely okay. A complete answer to your question must either be as long as a guidebook, or contain a link to one. Unfortunately I don’t know of any such guide.
